# Use StartActivityForResult() to take photos, but parent Activity is re-created after finish taking photos, why?

Tags: android

I use `Intent it = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);` to take photos by call up camera. And after finish that, the parent Activity is re-created, and a value which I used to keep the path of the picture is initialed to be null.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the system does not have enough RAM it can destroy your activity and recreate it back when it needs it. Put your presistent settings in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) and **onResume** load them back.

Every Activity which is **onResume** state (hidden from the user) can be automaticaly destroyed and then reacreated when needed.

Comment: Yes yes. I'm dealing this with SharedPreferences now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you call `finish()` after you `startActivityForResult()` call. Don't do this, it is removing your activity from activity stack.

Comment: No, I didn't call that. It was because of the shortage of RAM.